# Losing all view model data when using paged list

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, paging, pagedlist

Just finished adding paging to my view using the [Paged List](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) plugin and I am able to bring data back for one page only. If you click "Next" or any other page number available the page will resubmit itself and you wind up with a blank form.

I stepped through the code and saw that the view model object being passed back to the controller is completely null. Does anyone know a way around this (ie retaining the view model data when navigating to a different paged list page)?

**View Model**

```
public class ZipCodeIndex
{
    [DisplayName("Zip Code")]
    public string searchZip { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateCodes { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Effective on this date")]
    public string searchDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("State")]
    public string searchState { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Territory")]
    public string searchTerritory { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("New Territory")]
    public string newTerritory { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("New Description")]
    public string newDescription { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("New Effective Date")]
    public string newEffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory> pagedTerritoryList { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }

    public ZipCodeIndex() 
    {
        zipCodeTerritory = new List<ZipCodeTerritory>();
        SetStateCodes();
    }

    //Set state code drop down list
    private void SetStateCodes()
    {
        AgentResources db = new AgentResources();
        StateCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                      select z.StateCode).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = x,
                          Value = x
                      }).Distinct().ToList();

        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ViewResult Index(int? page, string errorMessage = "", ZipCodeIndex search = null)
    {
        //set Paged List counter variables
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        int pageSize = 300;

        //If TempData conntains information method call came from another controller action
        if (TempData.Count > 0)
        {
            //Instantiate ZipCodeIndex view model object if it exists
            search = (ZipCodeIndex)TempData["ZipCodeIndexData"];

            //Clear out previous search results
            search.zipCodeTerritory.Clear();
        }

        //Proceed with search
        try
        {
            //If search criteria is null page is loading for the first time so send blank view 
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchZip) &&
                String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchDate) &&
                String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchState))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchTerritory))
                {
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "State or Zip Code required for search.";
                }

                //Convert list to IPagedList for pagining on Index
                search.pagedTerritoryList = search.zipCodeTerritory.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

                return View(search);
            }

            //Determine if necessary search criteria has been sent
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchZip) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchState))
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Either State or Zip Code Must be Specified";

                //Convert list to IPagedList for pagining on Index
                search.pagedTerritoryList = search.zipCodeTerritory.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

                return View(search);
            }

            DateTime effectiveDate;

            //Convert date string to DateTime type
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchDate))
            {
                effectiveDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            else
            {
                effectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(search.searchDate);
            }

            //Conduct search by State Code/Date alone
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchZip))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchTerritory))
                {
                    search.zipCodeTerritory = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                               where z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState) &&
                                                     z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                                               select z).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    search.zipCodeTerritory = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                               where z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState) &&
                                                     z.IndDistrnId.Equals(search.searchTerritory) &&
                                                     z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                                               select z).ToList();
                }

                //Convert list to IPagedList for pagining on Index
                search.pagedTerritoryList = search.zipCodeTerritory.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

            }

            return View(search);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model Monet.ViewModel.ZipCodeIndex

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zip Code Territory Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

<h2>Zip Code Territory</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="error" id="searchErrors">
            @ViewBag.ErrorMessage            
        </div>    
        <br/>
        <div id="searchBox" class="boxMe">
            <div id="zipBox">
                @Html.Raw("Zip Code")
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.searchZip, new { style = "width: 300px;", placeholder = "Enter up to 35 comma separated zip codes" }) 
            </div>
            <div id="dateBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.searchDate, new { style="width: 80px;"})
                <div id="terrBox">
                     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchTerritory)
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.searchTerritory, new { style = "width: 30px;padding-left:10px;", maxLength = 3 })                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="stateBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchState)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.searchState, Model.StateCodes, "  ")
                <button type="submit" id="SearchButton">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    }

<br/>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="error" id="updateErrors">
    @ViewBag.UpdateAction            
</div>
@if (Model.zipCodeTerritory.Count > 0)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchZip)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchState)

        <div id="cloneBox">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newTerritory)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newTerritory, new { style = "width: 30px;padding-left:10px;", maxLength = 3 })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newDescription)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newDescription, new { style = "width: 250px;padding-left:10px;", maxLength = 30 })  
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newEffectiveDate)     
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newEffectiveDate, new { style = "width: 80px;padding-left:10px;" })   
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="buttonDiv">
            <button type="submit" id="CloneButton" name="button" value="clone">Update Selected Items</button>
            <button type="submit" id="deleteButton" name="button" value="delete">Delete Selected Items</button>            
        </div>
        <div id="pagingDiv">
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model.pagedTerritoryList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page })) 
        </div>
        <table id="thetable" class="tablesorter" >
            <thead>
                <th>@Html.CheckBox("SelectAll")</th>
                <th>Channel</th>
                <th>Territory</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>Effective</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Last Update By</th>
                <th>Last Update Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.pagedTerritoryList.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Update)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Update)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ChannelCode)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ChannelCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].IndDistrnId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].IndDistrnId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].DrmTerrDesc)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].DrmTerrDesc)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].StateCode)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].StateCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ZipCode)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ZipCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EffectiveDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zipCodeTerritory[i].EffectiveDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EndDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EndDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].LastUpdateId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].LastUpdateId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].LastUpdateDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].LastUpdateDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Id })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Id)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Found [this article](http://pastebin.com/P0FuyUte) and altered my `@Html.PagedListPager` accordingly, however no luck (still passing a `null` view model object and now even passing null `page` parameter...)

```
    <div id="pagingDiv">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.pagedTerritoryList, page => Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary()
            {
                { "Page", Page},
                { "search", Model }
            }), PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand it has been a year or so since this question has been attended to, but I recently found a simple solution for this problem and wanted to share. The last answer was partially correct, but there is a much easier way to accomplish this.

Here is some example code of passing a viewmodel data from view to controller and retaining data.

Lets say this is your viewmodel:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public string data1 { get; set; }
    public string data2 { get; set; }
    public string data3 { get; set; }
    public string data4 { get; set; }
    public IPagedList SearchResults { get; set; }
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }
}
```

And your simple viewmodel constructed method (no actual search code, used as example):

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model) {

    //code using and constructing your returned search results

    var pageNumIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
    model.SearchR = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, 25);
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view, the @Html.PagedListPager would look like:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchR, Page => Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary() {
    { "Page", Page },
    { "data1", Model.data1 },
    { "data2", Model.data2 },
    { "data3", Model.data3 },
    { "data4", Model.data4 },
}),
PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
```

This approach implements the RouteValueDictionary() directly into the Html.PagedListPager.

I struggled finding a solution of @Html.PagedListPager using the viewmodel approach until discovering the RouteValueDictionary() direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your revised code will only send the parameters to the Index page: Page, and search. Page being the page value you want, but search probably being the ToString of your model class.

I've been grappling with this issue myself, and came up with the following solution: 
I've added this method to my model, and

```
public RouteValueDictionary GenerateRouteValueDictionary(int page)
    {
        Page = page;
        RouteValueDictionary dic = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => Page), Page },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => PreviousSortField), PreviousSortField },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SortOrder), SortOrder },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchString), SearchString }, 
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => IncludeHidden), IncludeHidden },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchOperator1), SearchOperator1 },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchField1), SearchField1 },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchField1Value), SearchField1Value },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => WhereOperator), WhereOperator },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchOperator2), SearchOperator2 },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchField2), SearchField2 },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => SearchField2Value), SearchField2Value },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => FilterByDummyLocations), FilterByDummyLocations },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => FilterByDummyProfile), FilterByDummyProfile },
            { QueryHelper.Print(() => FilterNoDevice), FilterNoDevice }
        };
        return dic;
    }
```

And from my cshtml, I generate the paged list as follows:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults, page => Model.GenerateRouteValueDictionary(page)));
```

(QueryHelper.Print is just a method that prints the name of the property I'm supplying... so I'm effectively recreating the query string for every link. Probably not the nicest way to handle this, but it works.

There's an alternative approach, where you first set the page number on the model, then supply the model itself:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults, page => Url.Action(action, Model.SetPage(page)))
```

And using this additional model method:

```
    public SearchPbxUsersModel SetPage(int page)
    {
        Page = page;
        SearchPbxUsersModel myModel = this.MemberwiseClone() as SearchPbxUsersModel;
        myModel.SearchResults = null;
        return myModel;
    }
```

Instead of cloning, you could also null any values you don't like (and you must even null certain values, e.g. the IPagedList pagedTerritoryList).

There's one caveat with either approach:

If you also have a multiselect control, you'll get stuck either way and will have to write your own action links manually (what a pain). Using the first approach won't work because with multiselect you have the query string property for the multiselect control multiple times (and that won't work with any dictionary), and with the second approach, your container holding the selected values (e.g. a List or IEnumerable) will get ToString()'ed, so instead of seeing your selected values, your model will hold one value which is the tostring of the container.